# Loading only administration messages for groups with Facebook Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

my simple goal is following: i would get the news feed from a facebook group, but only the messages from the administration himself. as a examples, i would get the news from this groupb https://www.facebook.com/wirsindhelden?sk=wall&filter=2

But only the posts from the admin and not the fan-posts. i tried the facebook graph api, but i only get all posts from the wall. i don't find any filter or working param to fix this. then i saw the rss-link on the fanpage and tried to fetch this... in this feed are only the admin-posts, but only 30 or less... and not enough data as in the json from the graph.

Have anybody a working solution to fix this problem: i only need a clean json response from facebook with all admin-posts from a fanpage, that's it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://graph.facebook.com/wirsindhelden/posts?access_token=XYZ
basically graph api only you don't get all the fans posts...

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Simple change the /feed in the URL with /posts